# AcrobatReader and FormWeb

Tags: webforms, acrobat

Hi
I wrote a webForm that is used to display a ".pdf" document receiving from one other webForm the path of the file by queryString.

The all is working well but if from acrobat reader somebody try to save the file in local on openDialog is displayed the name of webForm ("PopVisPdf.pdf").

the question is:

How can display the real name of file in this situation ?

the code of webForm that I use:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CryptoString Uncrypt = new CryptoString();
        string id = Request.QueryString["Id"];
        string pathPdf = Uncrypt.DecryptString(id);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.TransmitFile(pathPdf);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Thankyou in advance for helping

Piercarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved from myself.
well only need to call the winform that show the file with this string:

http://MyForm.aspx/FileName.pdf?id=.........

where "FileName.pdf is the name that I want to give

Is working beatifull

Hope that can be usefull to somebody else.

Regards

Piercarlo